# kotlin change in SDK 29 causing compile issue

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom Preferences class which uses Kotlin extensions to return a Preference string.
It works perfect in API 28, but won't compile in API 29. With Googles new rules about not allowing app updates that target below API 30, I need to update this app, but can't figure out this basic issue.

Here is my Preference class:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import kotlin.properties.ReadWriteProperty
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

class PreferenceProperty<T> internal constructor(
    private val getter: SharedPreferences.(key: String, defaultValue: T) -> T,
    private val setter: SharedPreferences.Editor.(key: String, value: T) -> SharedPreferences.Editor,
    private val defaultValue: T,
    private val key: String? = null
) : ReadWriteProperty<SharedPreferences, T> {
    override fun getValue(thisRef: SharedPreferences, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return thisRef.getter(key ?: property.name, defaultValue)
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: SharedPreferences, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        thisRef.edit().setter(key ?: property.name, value).apply()
    }
}

fun SharedPreferences.stringPreference(defaultValue: String): PreferenceProperty<String> {
    return PreferenceProperty(
        SharedPreferences::getString,
        SharedPreferences.Editor::putString,
        defaultValue
    )
}

fun SharedPreferences.nullableStringPreference(defaultValue: String? = null): PreferenceProperty<String?> {
    return PreferenceProperty(
        SharedPreferences::getString,
        SharedPreferences.Editor::putString,
        defaultValue
    )
}
```

I am using the stringPreference, but also need nullableStringPreference for other parts of the code.
I use it as follows:

```
var notificationToken: String by stringPreference("")
```

But I get this error:

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is PreferenceProperty<String?> but PreferenceProperty<String> was expected
```

So the issue is that, since API 29, it returns `String?`.

Does anyone know change in API29 caused this and how to work around it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird. There must have been something changed in how nullability annotations are interpretted to make it stricter. I don't see any signature or annotation change on the `getString()` method between the two versions of the SDK. Logically, this is the correct treatment of the return value since it's marked `@Nullable`. There's no annotation for the return value to match the nullability of a method parameter.

You can replace

```
SharedPreferences::getString
```

with

```
{ key, def -> getString(key, def)!! }
```

To get it working again. `!!` is logically safe here, but if you're pedantic about avoiding it you could use:

```
{ key, def -> getString(key, null) ?: def }
```